# My s3 bucket policy wouldn't apply to existing or newly created buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

```
LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Id: "S3-LifeCycle-Purger"
            ExpirationInDays: 90
            NoncurrentVersionExpirationInDays: 90
            Status: Enabled
```

it doesn't apply the policy to already existing buckets and if I make a new one it doesn't add it

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that the snippet of code you provided **is correct and it works**. I tested it in a simple template for S3:

```
---
Resources:

  MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Id: "S3-LifeCycle-Purger"
            ExpirationInDays: 90
            NoncurrentVersionExpirationInDays: 90
            Status: Enabled
```

If it does not work for you, then the cause is outside of the `LifecycleConfiguration` settings.

Comment: so how did you test it you make a bucket through the console right?

Comment: @thecoderguy No. Its cloudformation template. I pasted it in my answer.

Comment: ok, I have a feeling it worked, I am just new to it that's all, but how would you know it worked? like where do I look because I am not seeing it any of my buckets.